# How to call ABAP code after releasing a Purchase Order?

Tags: abap, purchase-order, badi

I want to trigger an IDoc or Web-service after releasing a purchase order. What is the best way to do it? Via output determination (what would be the condition in this case?) or via a BADI or user exit?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **M06E0005** user-exit. It is used to change release role determination during release workflow events and can be utilized to run custom code.

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of requests, I would suggest to use SAP Business Workflow. In your case, the SAP standard will trigger the event `Released` of the business object `BUS2012` (Purchase Order) in the Business Object Repository (BOR). With transaction `SWETYPV`, you can attach consumers to this event. The consumers will automatically be called (if workflow is active in your system, of course). A consumer may be a workflow, a function module or a method of an ABAP OO class.

Advantages, compared to other possible solutions:

- The coupling itself is pure customizing, no need to add ABAP code to the purchase order processing.
- The coupling is loose (via event), reducing dependencies.
- The coupling can be activated and deactivated dynamically via workflow customizing.
- There are monitoring tools to trace the triggered events and the execution of their event handlers (e.g. transaction `SWEL`).
- SAP Business workflow is classical and well-tried technology.